# Vue does not update model after axios response

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue component which basically does the following things:

1. When mounted, load some data from a remote API and initialize the Vue model with the response data.
2. When submitting a form, some information need to be removed from the `userData` object which are only provided by the backend.
3. The response of the update will again contain the object which was deleted in #2.

The problem is: Although the reponse data are correct (`response.data` contains `userData.someNestedObject`), Vue does not update the view, i.e. `this.userData.someNestedObject` is not displayed. But I don't understand why.

```js
data() {
  return {
    userData: {}
  }
}
async mounted() {
  const response = await ApiService.getUser();
  this.userData = response.data;
},
methods: {
  async submit() {
    // delete some object from userData which must not be included in the update request
    delete this.userData.someNestedObject;
    // update user and update data with response
    const response = await ApiSerivce.updateUser(this.userData);
    this.userData = response.data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you output `response.data` from `ApiSerivce.updateUser` request ? Are you sure it contain someNestedObject?

Answer (score 1):

This happening because Vue did not wrap the `userData` object with reactive properties. To fix this you either have to fully describe `userData` in `data`
like:

```js
data() {
  return {
    userData: {
      someNestedObject: null
    }
  }
}
```

Or reassign entire `userData` object when deleting property
Like:

```js
methods: {
  async submit() {
    // delete some object from userData which must not be included in the update request
    const newUserData = this.userData;
    delete newUserData.someNestedObject;
    this.userData = newUserData;

    // update user and update data with response
    const response = await ApiSerivce.updateUser(this.userData);
    this.userData = response.data;
  }
}
```

Comment: He already reassign entire `userData` in last line of **submit** method.

Answer (score 1):

From the Vue documentation (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

"Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion... a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive."

To add reactive properties to an object you have to use

```
Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

or

```
this.$set(this.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

Or you can use Object.assign to assign new properties to an new object with properties from the old object and the new object:

```
this.userData = Object.assign({}, this.userData, response.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the [answer by @ikkoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69256926/478406) pointed me into the right direction. I needed to do a *deep copy* of the objects, so that all their properties and inner objects are copied as well.

I ended up using [lodash's cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) function which works and solves my issue:

`this.userData = cloneDeep(response.data)`

For simple objects you could also use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject))`.